# hinge jointをスクリプトから操作したい

Tags: unity3d

Unityのhinge jointをスクリプトから操作しようとしたところ、targetVelocityの値が変わらず、全く動きません。
useMotorのチェックは入っていますし、エラーも出ていません。
インスペクターで直接値をいじると動きます。

バージョンは2022.1.23f1と2021.3.22f1で試しました。

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class motor : MonoBehaviour

public HingeJoint Joint;

void Update()
{
　var Motor = Joint.motor;
　Motor.targetVelocity= 360;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ちょっと厄介な話なのですが…。

まずは、`HingeJoint.moter` の型である [`JointMotor` のマニュアル](https://docs.unity3d.com/ja/2022.2/ScriptReference/JointMotor.html)を見てください。
「struct in UnityEngine」と書かれています。
つまり、`JointMotor` は構造体(struct)なんです。

C#の構造体の説明は、自分もあまり説明ができないので、以下を見てもらいたいです。

- [構造体 - C# によるプログラミング入門 | ++C++; // 未確認飛行 C](https://ufcpp.net/study/csharp/resource/rm_struct/)
- [値型と参照型 - C# によるプログラミング入門 | ++C++; // 未確認飛行 C](https://ufcpp.net/study/csharp/oo_reference.html)

(他にも、検索して調べてみてください。結構大事な話です)

構造体は値型であり、クラスとは違います。
例えば、以下の例。

```cs
    class Hoge {
        public int a;
    }
    
    Hoge hoge0 = new Hoge();
    hoge0.a = 1;
    Hoge hoge1 = hoge0;
    hoge1.a = 2;
    Debug.Log($"hoge0.a = {hoge0.a}, hoge1.a = {hoge1.a}.");
```

通常クラスの代入は、同じオブジェクトを指すことになるので、ログには「hoge0.a = 2, hoge1.a = 2.」と出力されます。

```cs
    struct Hoge {
        public int a;
    }

    Hoge hoge0 = new Hoge();
    hoge0.a = 1;
    Hoge hoge1 = hoge0;
    hoge1.a = 2;
    Debug.Log($"hoge0.a = {hoge0.a}, hoge1.a = {hoge1.a}.");
```

というように構造体にした場合、構造体の代入は新たなオブジェクトの作成と、各メンバの代入となります。
つまり、以下のような感じです。

```cs
    Hoge hoge0 = new Hoge();
    hoge0.a = 1;
    Hoge hoge1 = new Hoge();
    hoge1.a = hoge0.a;
    hoge1.a = 2;
    Debug.Log($"hoge0.a = {hoge0.a}, hoge1.a = {hoge1.a}.");
```

ですので、代入先の`hoge1`のメンバに変更を加えても、代入元の`hoge0`には変更が加わらないことになります。
よって、ログには「hoge0.a = 1, hoge1.a = 2.」と出力されます。

どうすればいいかは、[`JointMotor`のマニュアル](https://docs.unity3d.com/ja/2022.2/ScriptReference/JointMotor.html)のサンプルコードのように、代入して値を変更した後、再度`HingeJoint.motor`に再代入すればいいでしょう。

```cs
    JointMotor motor = Joint.motor;
    motor.targetVelocity = 360;
    Joint.motor = motor;  // 再代入
```